# Small space between svg and path

Tags: html, css, svg

This is my path tag size (g tag is same size)

[image]

And this is my SVG tag size

[image]

There is space between them

These are the inline attributes...

```
<svg preserveAspectRatio="none" class="JDicon JDicon__svg JDicon--white JDicon--large" alignment-baseline="central" version="1.1" data-tip="false" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
<g>
<path d="M56.562,6.875 L3.437,6.875 C1.539,6.875 -0.000,5.336 -0.000,3.437 C-0.000,1.539 1.539,-0.000 3.437,-0.000 L56.562,-0.000 C58.461,-0.000 60.000,1.539 60.000,3.437 C60.000,5.336 58.461,6.875 56.562,6.875 ZM3.437,24.062 L32.656,24.062 C34.555,24.062 36.094,25.601 36.094,27.500 C36.094,29.398 34.555,30.937 32.656,30.937 L3.437,30.937 C1.539,30.937 -0.000,29.398 -0.000,27.500 C-0.000,25.601 1.539,24.062 3.437,24.062 ZM43.437,30.937 C41.539,30.937 40.000,29.398 40.000,27.500 C40.000,25.601 41.539,24.062 43.437,24.062 L43.562,24.062 C45.461,24.062 47.000,25.601 47.000,27.500 C47.000,29.398 45.461,30.937 43.562,30.937 L43.437,30.937 ZM3.437,47.125 L56.562,47.125 C58.461,47.125 60.000,48.664 60.000,50.562 C60.000,52.461 58.461,54.000 56.562,54.000 L3.437,54.000 C1.539,54.000 -0.000,52.461 -0.000,50.562 C-0.000,48.664 1.539,47.125 3.437,47.125 Z">
</path>
</g>
</svg>
```

This is css for svg

```
{
    width: 1.8rem;
    height: 1.8rem;
}
```

I am trying to figure out why this space exists.

https://codepen.io/colton123/pen/qBEGwLL

Comment: please post code rather than simply images

Comment: @RamRaider  Ops.. sorry  i edited it

Comment: your viewBox is 64 x 64, your path is smaller than that.

Comment: @Robert Longson  hummmm... can i make it fit at viewBox ?

Comment: easiest to just change the viewBox, no?

Comment: @ Robert Longson  Oh yes work! i just expected it automatically fit  because  preserveAspectRatio="none"  attribute...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things: Your icon is not a perfect square, and there is a gap in the icon itself on the right side.

First, with the `<svg>` set to 1.8rem (32px in CodePen) the `<g>` is 30x27px. If you changed the height and width of `<svg>` to 3rem (48px in CodePen) the `<g>` would be 45x40.5px. Since you are forcing `<svg>` into a square, there will be a gap.

Second, the width of `<g>` should match the width of `<svg>`, but it is always 93.75% of the width. **This means there is a 6.25% gap in the icon itself.**

Answer (score 1):

Hello please see this and solve your issue of SVG. Thanks

```css
svg {
  width: 2rem;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<svg class="JDicon JDicon__svg JDicon--white JDicon--large" alignment-baseline="central" version="1.1" data-tip="false" viewBox="0 0 62 56"><g><path d="M56.562,6.875 L3.437,6.875 C1.539,6.875 -0.000,5.336 -0.000,3.437 C-0.000,1.539 1.539,-0.000 3.437,-0.000 L56.562,-0.000 C58.461,-0.000 60.000,1.539 60.000,3.437 C60.000,5.336 58.461,6.875 56.562,6.875 ZM3.437,24.062 L32.656,24.062 C34.555,24.062 36.094,25.601 36.094,27.500 C36.094,29.398 34.555,30.937 32.656,30.937 L3.437,30.937 C1.539,30.937 -0.000,29.398 -0.000,27.500 C-0.000,25.601 1.539,24.062 3.437,24.062 ZM43.437,30.937 C41.539,30.937 40.000,29.398 40.000,27.500 C40.000,25.601 41.539,24.062 43.437,24.062 L43.562,24.062 C45.461,24.062 47.000,25.601 47.000,27.500 C47.000,29.398 45.461,30.937 43.562,30.937 L43.437,30.937 ZM3.437,47.125 L56.562,47.125 C58.461,47.125 60.000,48.664 60.000,50.562 C60.000,52.461 58.461,54.000 56.562,54.000 L3.437,54.000 C1.539,54.000 -0.000,52.461 -0.000,50.562 C-0.000,48.664 1.539,47.125 3.437,47.125 Z"></path></g></svg>
```

Your  should be viewBox="0 0 62 54" instead of viewBox="0 0 62 62"